Self signed certificate for Minimal API accepted by Curl but rejected by EDGE

Create the cert using Powershell
New-SelfSignedCertificate -CertStoreLocation Cert:\LocalMachine\My -DnsName "localhost" -FriendlyName "localhost" -NotAfter (Get-Date).AddYears(10)

Launch "Manage computer certificates" (certmgr. msc)

Navigate to Certificates - Local Computer > Personal > Certificates to find your newly created certificate.

Works fine with Curl. And get a response "Hello World"
curl https://localhost:5061/Hello

Goto EDGE And browse https://localhost:5061/Hello, gets ERR_UNSAFE_PORT


I am calling from my own test site (Not secure yet.  http://localhost:5062/Index.html), needs to call a WebAPI using Ajax within the same computer https://localhost:5061/something to communicate to a hardware device

It's not the cert. This port, and a number of others, are used in attacks (by malicious websites) against your system, so Chrome and thus Edge rejects them. See https://superuser.com/questions/188058/which-ports-are-considered-unsafe-by-chrome and more linked there. (And this is not programming or development.)

@dave_thompson_085 holyxxxx, wasted me 1 whole day just because of a bad choice @_@
